# How to findout the length of CheckBoxlist on serverside?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, checkboxlist

I have a checkboxlist in a div which shows name gettin data from db.
I have to findout the lenght of this checkboxlist on OnSelectedIndexChanged to make some db action on selected item/value.
Someone help me out!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Presuming your `CheckBoxList` variable is called `checkboxlist` use the following to determine the amount of items:

```
int numberOfItems = checkboxlist.Items.Count
```

The [`CheckBoxList.Items`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.items.aspx) property returns a [`ListItemCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.aspx) containing your controls, from here you can use the count property to determine the length of the list or the number of items it contains.

Comment: So, now how to checked for a particular checkbox for checked or not ?

Comment: @Fly In SKY - That's a different question. If this question has been answered by any of the solutions posted so far, mark it so and post another question relating to your next problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:CheckBoxList id="Check1" RepeatLayout="flow" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" >
 <asp:ListItem>Item 1</asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem>Item 2</asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem>Item 3</asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem>Item 4</asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem>Item 5</asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem>Item 6</asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Protected Sub Check1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Check1.SelectedIndexChanged

```
Dim items As String = Check1.Items.Count
```

End Sub